# Simple image with text slider/rotator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I need to create a simple image + text rotator. Like on the picture https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Public/rotator.jpg?_subject_uid=6084477&w=AADd9lfxtZZzhWbGMTKwMdWn3eVjgGZ_OplgxVycsivbHA.

It will be a small block in the body of the page. Elements should change automatically after certain time, but it should be also possible to rotate them with arrows.

I am a newbie in programming, so my apologies if this is too obvious question. I suppose I should use CSS and Javascript here?
Also I've tried to google for some code example, but everything I find looks too complicated, while I need really light and basic functionality.

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea of something like this is to have a div with `position: relative` and width and height of one image. Lets call it `#images_holder`. In this `#images_holder` would be another div with `position: absolute`, height of one image, and width of all images. Lets call this inner div `#moving_part`. In this `#moving_part` you can put your images. If you want to have images with text, create div with `float: left`, `position: relative` and width and height of one image for each image. Lets call this divs `.image_holder`. Inside `.image_holder` you can put your images and texts for example as spans with `position: absolute`.

With something like this you are able to move the `#moving_part` by setting `left` with javascript.

I wrote an example of this using jQuery, but it's intended just to show you the way, it's not complete solution. It has some flaws, like if you click multiple times on move_left_button while moving, it can move your images outside viewable area, as the checking if it can be moved is done as soon as you click the button and it does not consider if it is already moving. To solve this you should use for example `data-moving` attribute, set it to true when moving is started and to false when it's finished, and start moving only if it is set to false. It would be also good idea if the width and height were dynamicly obtained from elements instead of hardcoding it. With this code as it is you will have to put your own values for widths and heights, and calculate when moving should be allowed based on image width, count of images and current left value.

Also this would work only if you have just one slider per page. If you want to have more you have to change ids to classes, and rewrite the code so it move only moving_part of the images_holder you clicked. Something like `$( ".images_holder" ).each( function(){ $this_moving_part = $( this ).find( ".moving_part" ); /* and so on... */ } );`

Here is Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Lc7cc7u/

HTML:

```
<div id="images_holder">
    <div id="move_left_button">LEFT</div>
    <div id="move_right_button">RIGTH</div>
    <div id="moving_part" data-direction="to_left">
        <div class="image_holder">
            <span>image 1</span>
            <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="image_holder">
            <span>image 2</span>
            <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="image_holder">
            <span>image 3</span>
            <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#images_holder {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 480px;
    height: 360px;
    color: red;
}
#moving_part {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 1440px; /* image_width * number_of_images */
    height: 360px;
    left: 0;
}
.image_holder {
    float: left;
    width: 480px;
    height: 360px;
    position: relative;
}
.image_holder span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 200px;
}

#move_left_button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
#move_right_button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$( "#move_left_button" ).click( function() {
        move_left();
} );

$( "#move_right_button" ).click( function() {
        move_right();
} );

function move_left() {
    if( get_acct_left() >= -480 ) {
        $( "#moving_part" ).animate( {
            left: "-=480px"
        }, 1000, function() {
            if( get_acct_left() <= -480 * 2 ) {
                $( "#moving_part" ).attr( "data-direction", "to_right" );
            }
        } );
    }
}
function move_right() {
    if( get_acct_left() < 0 ) {
        $( "#moving_part" ).animate( {
            left: "+=480px"
        }, 1000, function() {
            if( get_acct_left() >= 0 ) {
                $( "#moving_part" ).attr( "data-direction", "to_left" );
            }
        } );
    }
}

function get_acct_left() {
    return parseInt( $( "#moving_part" ).css( "left" ) );
}

function move_to_next() {
    if( $( "#moving_part" ).attr( "data-direction" ) === "to_left" ) {
        move_left();
    } else {
        move_right();
    }
}

setInterval( move_to_next, 4000 );
```